# SVG Text element not getting added in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to add a html content in svg text element. Its working in chrome but not in IE11..can somebody help me...its very simple code.

```
<svg width="400" height="110">
<g id="test">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
    <text id="svgtext" x="0" y="15" fill="red"></text>
    </g>
```

Jquery code

```
 $("#svgtext").html("&#10006")
```

here is the link for fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/6nz0recd/

check in IE, it doesnt work

Comment: Perhaps you could try adding a semicolon after `&#10006`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE doesn't support the jquery html method on SVG entities. You can use the text method instead though.

```
$("#svgtext").text("\u2716")
```

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle with new fork and answer here is the link which works 
http://jsfiddle.net/L9wd79y2/